# Import existing Android Studio Project and view "Storyboard"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a long time iOS developer but brand new to Android development and am trying to import an already built Android app into Android Studio, the problems I am running into are

1) What is the right way to import this Android project I downloaded off the internet

2) What file in this project should I select to view the "Storyboard" of this application

Below is a screenshot of the file explorer from this project, I am currently inside of the folder called "My Project".

[image]

Comment: start android studio, then click import gradle project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *2 options* to import an existing Android project into AS:

1. **Select the Import project** (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc...), shown in the below image. Even though you know it's an Android Studio project, you should still try to import it this way, because sometimes the generated files are not customized for the environment.

[image]

2. **Select File -> New -> Import Project**. As shown in the image below.

[image]

---

The equivalent of the storyboards in Android are the XML layouts, which you can found under the res folder on the Android View in AS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidStudio File->Open > Select root folder of the project.

Layouts are the storyboard for android.It's inside the app/src/main/res/layout directory.